# Why can't you pass a std::atomic variable to a thread by reference? (but you can by pointer)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pass-by-reference, atomic

I am trying to write a simple C++ application that uses threads and only has to manage a couple of shared variables between the threads. In order to do that simply I decided I would just make these variables `std::atomic` so I don't have to worry about manually locking and unlocking things.

I tried to start with a simple example where I create an `atomic` variable in main and pass it to the thread. I was surprised when I attempted to compile it and got a bunch of barely decipherable template related compilation errors.

**Passing an atomic by reference:**

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

// Causes an ugly compiler error
void func(std::atomic<int>& i) {
    // Do something that uses "i" in the thread
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<int> i;
    std::thread t(func, i);

    // Do something that uses "i" in main

    t.join();
}
```

However if I simply pass the atomic variable by pointer it does work.

**Passing an atomic by pointer:**

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

// Compiles fine
void func(std::atomic<int>* i) {
    // Do something that uses "i" in the thread
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<int> i;
    std::thread t(func, &i);

    // Do something that uses "i" in main

    t.join();
}
```

What exactly is happening here? The error (too long to post here, but you can compile it and see) seems to say something about `std::atomic` not having a copy constructor... but I'm passing it by reference. Why on earth would it be trying to make a copy when passed by reference?

Comment: `std::thread t(func, i);` you seem to think this conveys that `i` is sent by reference to *that* call, much less eventually conveyed by reference to to the invocation of `func` thereafter by the controlling thread library. Did you try a reference wrapper? `std::thread t(func, std:;ref(i));`

Comment: Thanks that works :)